Pacstrap -K fails with unhelpful error message
I hope I haven't missed anything obvious and if you need more information I can supply it. I'm trying to manually install arch from a live usb to a secondary partition on my laptop. I'm using the most recent (as of writing) iso from the arch linux website.
I connected to the internet, formatted the partition (btrfs), mounted it to /mnt, and ran pacstrap -K /mnt base linux linux-firmware intel-ucode systemd iwd nano pacman. This failed with error: command failed to execute successfully. Does anyone know either how to fix this or enable logging so I know what went wrong? I attached a picture of the output.

No big deal. It's just because you didn't include btrfs-progs when you pacstrap. (And fsck.btrfs is really just a no-op / placeholder script.) It won't cause you trouble booting the installation. (More precisely, I think as a result mkinitcpio didn't "exit 0" even when the cause was just shown as "WARNING" instead of "ERROR", and pacman in turn considered it failed and show you the message as "error".)

@TomYan wow that worked! Thank you!

Your arch system(on non-volatile drive) doesn't have the btrfs-progs package to mount the root filesystem.
Add btrfs-progs to argments of pacstrap.
If you want to use new filesystem, you need to find xxx-progs package and install it to make your kernel to read and write data with new filesystem.


serspace utilities for file systems that will be used on the system—for the purposes of e.g. file system creation and fsck,
utilities for accessing and managing RAID or LVM if they will be used on the system,


https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide#Install_essential_packages
